# Choosing module SIM for pushing data form car-mounted microcontroller to remote server

Tags: networking, wireless, router

Assume that I have a box attached into a car and its function is receiving sensors data (GPS, temperature, speed) and push these data onto a remote sever through 2G/3G. Because I need this system be real time, so I need a module SIM to continuously transfer data to remote server. So my criteria for the module Sim is it must be stable, fast enough to push sensors data to sever (maybe twice in a minute). 
Can you suggest me some modules Sim can handle well this situation ?

Comment: [Unless your definition of real time is >300ms](https://hpbn.co/mobile-networks/), probably not happening. Beyond that, it's not up to the SIM, but up to the networking equipment on your and the towers' end. Why do you need to push this data over cellular?

Comment: I have researched about other solutions such as LPWAN (lora) but my country still haven't supported it. 
About wifi, my city doesnt have whole wifi coverage, too. Just few points.
So I decide to use 2G/3G technology to transfer data.

Comment: My suggestion would just be to research who had the best coverage in your area.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR: It doesn't matter, pick a carrier with the best service in your area and get the appropriate SIM.

To understand why it doesn't matter, [let's understand what a SIM is.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module)

> A subscriber identity module or subscriber identification module (SIM) is an integrated circuit that is intended to securely store the [international mobile subscriber identity (IMSI) number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_mobile_subscriber_identity) and its related key, which are used to identify and authenticate subscribers on mobile telephony devices (such as mobile phones and computers).

The SIM is only being queried occasionally to check your identity on the network. Think of it as your ID when you go to a club: it only gets checked to verify your identity; it has no role in what you do in the club besides that.

All the actual transmission is up to the hardware in your phone and in the cell tower. Since you have no control over the cell towers, all you can do is choose a phone with good hardware and a network with good coverage in your area.

Comment: I mean what module Sim not only Sim. As far as I know, on the market, there are some module Sim support 2G such as module Sim800, Sim900, arduino Shield GSM...

Comment: I see. In that case, we'll need to know more about your intended setup: what existing hardware are you trying to use? How much data are you pushing? Power constraints? Budget?

Comment: Thank for your advice. I will consider them in choosing the best option.